# How to extract data from gcf file?

Tags: c#

Good greeting

Please help me>>>
I want to read a (gcf file) in Visual Studio C#.

The gcf file stores the reading of earthquake data.

My regards

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I suppose that gcf stands for `Guralp Compressed Format` not `Game Cache File`.
So GCF is binary format and you should read it as binary. 
In short:

> Each GCF block consists of two parts: a header and a body. For data
>   blocks, this body contains first differences of the sample values, and
>   for status blocks, the body contains text status information

1. System ID  Coded as a base 36 number.
2. Stream ID  Coded as a base 36 number.
3. Date Code
4. Data format

   reserved

   Sample Rate

   Compression Code

   Number of Records

If you want to decode or convert it, [this link](http://geophysics.eas.gatech.edu/GTEQ/Scream4.4/GCF_Specification.htm) will be helpfull.

Also you should look at [specification](https://www.guralp.com/apps/ok?doc=GCF_format).

Comment: Link only answers are bad. What if the link become dead ?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Comment: I don't think I should post whole format specification.

Comment: @KrivitskiyGrigoriy There's some middle ground between nothing and everything.  When that link goes dead, your answer will become useless.  That's why we ask that the code not merely be a link.